# Offline Aerial Mapping with Bing and OSM Droid

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, bing-maps, osmdroid

I have a requirement to use offline Aerial photography mapping. My choice has been to use OSMDroid as it caches the map tiles which can be used when mobile reception dies or is non-existant (exactly as I would want it if I had to write it myself).

I have managed to get Bing Aerial maps to work with OSM droid using [this](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-third-party/src/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/bing/BingMapTileSource.java?r=959) tile source provider and the following code in the activity which will display the map.

```
MapView map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
try{
  BingMapTileSource.initMetaData(this);
  String m_locale =   Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
  BingMapTileSource bing = new BingMapTileSource(m_locale,null);
  bing.setStyle(BingMapTileSource.IMAGERYSET_AERIAL);
  map.setTileSource(bing);
}
catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, this proivder is online only. Inspecting the file system of my phone I can see that the bing map tiles are downloaded. So what I would like to do is develop the provider to work online as is and offline when no data connection is available.

I can see that in some way I must used something like the [MapTileProviderBasic.class](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/MapTileProviderBasic.java?r=633) to form a request chain, but really don't know where to go from there.

Comment: For offline tile sources, you may want to look at MOBAC.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Bing Maps Aerial imagery offline is against the terms of use of Bing Maps. Any app found doing this will be removed for the app store.